# Get other possible commands from web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have an app that creates a webservice and generally i'm sending an xml and the app executes:
Im' sending something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PostRequest>
<SetValue Name="Timeline.RestartScene" Type="Trigger" Value="false" />
</PostRequest>
```

Response in case of success is:

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PostReply Success="1" Status="OK">
  <SetValue Name="Timeline.RestartScene" Success="1" Status="OK"/>
</PostReply>
```

My question was if i can discover other commands than SetValue .
I tried but the response is always:

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PostReply Success="0" Status="Syntax error">
</PostReply>
```

I tried with WSDL but the response was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>wsdl /protocol:HttpPost h
ttp://localhost:5521/postbox
Microsoft (R) Web Services Description Language Utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Error: There was an error processing 'http://localhost:5521/postbox'.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:5521/postbox'.
  - The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

If you would like more help, please type "wsdl /?".
```

Also i tried with svcutil to get some info:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>svcutil http://localhost:
5521/postbox
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://localhost:5521/postbox' using WS-Me
tadata Exchange or DISCO.
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:5521/postbox

If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have acce
ss, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified addr
ess.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentat
ion at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.


WS-Metadata Exchange Error
    URI: http://localhost:5521/postbox

    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:552
1/postbox'.

    The content type text/xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not ma
tch the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If us
ing a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemen
ted properly. The first 109 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" enc
oding="utf-8"?>
<PostReply Success="0" Status="Invalid content type">
</PostReply>
'.


HTTP GET Error
    URI: http://localhost:5521/postbox

    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:5521/postbox'.

    The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.

If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"
```

Comment: Maybe that's not where the WSDL is located. What happens when you type that URL into a web browser? And have you tried adding "?wsdl" to the end of the URL?

Comment: Yes i tried forbiden 403